# Logitech Keyboard on MacBook Pro - right Ctrl key not mapping correctly

Tags: macbook, logitech-keyboard

I have a MacBook Pro, and plugged in a wireless mouse/keyboard combo.  Mouse works fine.  Because of my PC familiarity I go to:

```
System Preferences > Keyboard > Modifier Keys
```

And switch the inputs for Command and Control.  Everything works great, except that the RIGHT Ctrl key does not behave the same as the left Ctrl key.

This has the annoying effect that commands like Ctrl-C for copy or Ctrl-V for paste require I move my right hand over to do the action.  Anway this model of Logitech keyboard has no Command key on the right side, and I don't like the inboard location of the Command key anyway.  Can anyone tell me how to make the right Control key do the same as the left one?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The left `ctrl` and `alt` keys seem to generate different keycodes, but the right `ctrl` and `alt` keys seem to generate the same `right-alt` keycode when pressed, which means the OSX doesn't appear to differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I have a MacBook Air. For my Logitech K780 to copy, I used the "alt/cmd" button + c to copy highlighted text.

To paste, I used the "alt/cmd" button + v.

Answer (score -1):

I just found the solution to my LogiTech keyboard. The windows logo in the middle of the CRTL and ALT button will work as your CRTL. It's a weird key to use, but I hope it works for you too!

Comment: On a standard PC keyboard, the Windows logo key acts as Cmd ⌘ not Ctrl. There's no way to make any key to the right of spacebar act as Cmd, & AltGr will actually act as though Ctrl & Opt were pressed.

Answer (score -2):

It is because your keyboard is not compatible with Mac. I ran into the same problem so I checked the box that the mouse and keyboard came in and it only said compatible with Windows.

Comment: How do you know if the Logitech keyboard model of OP is the same as yours?